# Django url - No reverse match

Tags: django, python-3.x

Okay, to be clear I've searched and read, followed the official docs, tried multiple solutions from SOF, nothing seems to be working so I have to resort to shamefully asking for help.

I'm simply trying to generate urls the proper way.

root urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'|/', include('main.urls')),

]
```

urls.py:

```
app_name = 'main'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^vieworder/(?P<order_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.vieworder, name='vieworder'),
]
```

template file:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'main:vieworder' order.id %}">View</a></td>
```

also tried:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'main:vieworder' order_id=order.id %}">View</a></td>
```

Error:

`Reverse for 'vieworder' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['|/vieworder/(?P<order_id>d+)/$']`

I don't understand why this is not working. I tested the regex against vieworder/1/ in a regex tester and it works fine. Django even tells me in the error that it tried the correct url pattern, however the error really isn't very clear on what is actually wrong.

Comment: Can you show your root urlconf?

Comment: Added to original post @knbk

Comment: Show your model. What does your order ID look like? It says it's trying the right pattern so it seems like `order.id` doesn't match the regex for your argument. (Edit: Just the id field of your order model would be fine.)

Comment: The id is the the primary key added to all models by default, here is my full view.py though: [link](http://pastebin.com/AArAQpVx)

Answer (score 1):

Django is not able to reverse the use of a `|` character outside of a capturing group. However, I highly doubt you need it here.

Django always matches the first slash of the url, so there's no need to match the starting slash in your regex. Adding a starting slash would only match a second slash at the start of your url. Unless you want the url path to be `example.com//vieworder/1/` rather than `example.com/vieworder/1/`, you should just remove the slash from your pattern.

Since the first slash is already matched by Django, and there's nothing else between the first slash and the `vieworder/1/` part, you can just leave the include pattern empty:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('main.urls')),
]
```

This will match the url `example.com/vieworder/1/`, and allow Django to reverse the url.

---

As for your second problem:

You need to make the outer group a non-capturing group with `?:`:

```
url(r'^vieworder(?:/(?P<order_id>\d+))*/$', views.vieworder, name='vieworder'),
```

Django will substitute the outermost capturing group, which in this case should contain `/1` instead of `1`. By making it a non-capturing group, Django will substitute the argument `1` into the inner group instead of the outer group.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not working:
`Reverse for 'vieworder' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'order_id': 1}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['vieworder(/(?P<order_id>\\d+))*/$']`

Comment: @TazmanianTad It seems from the error message that you have changed the regex for the second part of the url. I tested the regex in your question, and it works fine for me.

Comment: I've tested both versions of my regex, the changed one is to allow /vieworder/ without an id, the problem is still unfortunately still occurring

Comment: @TazmanianTad Can you show the exact regexes you're currently using?

Comment: `url(r'^vieworder(/(?P<order_id>\d+))*/$', views.vieworder, name='vieworder')` is what I am currently using

Comment: You need to make the outer group a non-capturing group with `?:`: `r'^vieworder(?:/(?P<order_id>\d+))*/$'`. Django will substitute the outermost capturing group, which in this case should contain `/1` instead of `1`. By making it a non-capturing group, Django will substitute the argument `1` into the inner group instead of the outer group.

Comment: That worked, excellent. (Although I still don't understand why my first regex didn't work in the original post), I've had plenty of fun messing around with this so I am content with this answer! (If you post it as an answer I will mark it as such)